# Conditional to check position of previous matrix block

Tags: conditional, macro

I'm referencing the Pixel & Tonic sample craft template Happy Lager where in the article body template there's a macro to get the position of a block.

I'm trying to setup a conditional to check if the previous position of a block has been set to 'left'.

```
{% if prevPosition == 'left' %}
```

But that doesn't seem to work at all.

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager/blob/master/craft/templates/_includes/article_body.html

Comment: What is `prevPosition`? `{{dump(prevPosition)}}` to display it...

Comment: It's NULL even though the previous block has position left.

Comment: Just looking at that macro, `prevPosition` should be set properly in lines 32-184. You need to be sure it is defined outside of the for loop (line 20), or else you will get a new, `null` one every time.

Comment: Where are you trying to insert this conditional? Inside the macro?

Comment: No outside in the article body template